# My Kernel modules don't match those of the VirtualBox installation guide. Should I be concerned?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, kernel-modules

Fabian Lee : Software Architect's [steps to installing VitualBox](http://fabianlee.org/2017/04/03/virtualbox-installing-virtualbox-and-vagrant-on-ubuntu-14-0416-04/):
Make sure the kernel modules (vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpic) were loaded properly:

```
    $ lsmod | grep vboxdrv
vboxdrv 446464 3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
```

My kernel modules seem okay however the numbers don't match Fabian's:

```
 $ lsmod | grep vboxdrv
vboxdrv 471040  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number represents the size of the module in memory, and it’s normal for it to vary from one system to another — it depends on the kernel version it was built for, the version of the module being built, and the compiler and compiler settings used.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I'm setting up my first dev env. I know little about this stuff. I should go deeper into this architecture dev ops area. I tried installing VirtualBox on Lubuntu last night but something went wrong with the dependencies required for build-essential.